# Python Syntax Format

Tags: python, programming-languages, python-3.x

Since I am new to programming, I just want to understand the format the built-in functions is represented in the documentations. This is the one from python

> bytearray ([source[, encoding[,errors]]])

Why all the square brackets are terminated at the end? The brackets are nested. There is comma immediately after the square bracket too. Does it mean it takes only 3 arguments? Is the below same as the above one?

> bytearray ([source],[encoding],[errors])

I am not understanding the format it represents.

Comment: Stuff being in square brackets means it's optional. It being nested means it's optional, but the outer levels of nesting must be there if it is.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718903/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-function-class-documentation. Please research before asking.

Answer (score 4):

Brackets means something is optional. For instance `foo[bar]qux` could be either `fooqux` or `foobarqux`. You could treat it like a regular expression `foo(bar)?qux` in your head if that helps.

Thus `bytearray ([source[, encoding[,errors]]])` could be any one of

- `bytearray(source, encoding, errors)`
- `bytearray(source, encoding)`
- `bytearray(source)`
- `bytearray()`

This also shows that you need to open the brackets before the comma, and close them all at once. With your suggested `bytearray([source], [encoding], [errors])`, the options would be:

- `bytearray(source, encoding, errors)`
- `bytearray(source, , )`
- `bytearray(, , errors)`
- `bytearray(, , )`
- etc. (There are eight possibilities in total, I'm not going to type them all out.)